# The number of $p$-subsets of an $n$-set is $n$ choose $p$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that the number of subsets of cardinality $p$ of a set $E$ of cardinality 
$n$ is ${n \choose p}$. I've read a proof that I couldn't understand it basically says that for any injection $f:\{1,..,p\}\to E$ there is a subset of cardinality $p$ which is $\{f(1),\cdots , f(p)\}$ and in the other direction  any $p$-subset $\{e_1,\cdots,e_p\}$ of $E$ is the image of $\{1,\cdots,p\}$ of $p!$ distinct injections. Hence the result.
Is there a way to clarify this or to write another proof by constructing a bijection between the set of $p$-subsets of $E$ and some other set for which we can simply compute the cardinality ? thank you for your help!!

Comment: How did you define $\binom{n}{p}$?

Comment: It is $\dfrac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}$

Answer (score 0):

Order all $n$ elements of your set, and take the first $p$ as your subset. This clearly generates all $p$-size subsets. There are $n!$ ways to order the set. The order of the last $n-p$ many does not matter, nor does the order of the first $p$ matter; this will give the exact same subset. So $n!$ counts every effective subset $p! (n-p)!$ times, so we divide by that to get the right number. Which is ${n \choose p}$ in your definition.